# What is Debugging?

Tags: debugging

How does debugging work? When I write code in Xcode and something is wrong. I always look at the Red or Orange Triangles with exclamation marks.  This always helped me fix the problems. But when writing an app and it crashes there are no triangles. Just lots of code in the debugging console at the bottom of Xcode. Currently I am having this problem every time I press my `Back` button:

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

(I did add an `Objective C` exception breakpoint)

How do you fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugging is a methodical process of finding and reducing the number of bugs or defects in a program.

In terms of errors there are 3 that come to mind:

Syntax - your program will not compile due to your program not following the syntactical specifications of a particular language, essentially the compiler comes across code that it does not understand.

Run time errors - errors that occur while your program runs, basically your program attempts code that is not possible to carry out, for instance division by zero can cause a runtime error.

Logic errors - A program will compile and will not crash, though there will be unintended or undesired program behaviour.

When debugging runtime or logic errors it's especially helpful to use a debugger. This allows you to step through the code one line at a time and inspect the values held in all of your variables.